# How to fix "FileNotFoundError" when using proper code and file extension CSV?

Tags: csv, opencsv

I am trying to open a file with the extension .csv in python, however it keeps saying that the file is not found. I am copying the path from the side bar, so I don't believe that's the problem

I have tried to insert / and ./ before the path of the file
And r in front of the file name

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

bkgrnd = pd.read_csv('/Desktop/Sro/Natrium22.csv')
```

No matter what I've tried, it keeps saying `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas.read\_csv file not found despite correct path with raw text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165649/pandas-read-csv-file-not-found-despite-correct-path-with-raw-text)

Comment: You are putting `/` root to `/Desktop` please provide fully qualified filename

Answer (score 0):

you can import `csv` if file will be always `.csv`,

```
import csv

with open('C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sro\Natrium22.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
```

specifix on windows, it needs normalization of your pathname, maybe thats the issue,
try doing, will surely work,

```
import os
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.getcwd()
filePath = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Sro/Natrium22.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.normcase(os.path.join(cwd, filePath)))
print(data)
```

you can try even,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

bkgrnd = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sro\Natrium22.csv')
print(bkgrnd)
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-20-db80559c71db>", line 6
    for row in csv_reader:
                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: EOF at line 6 means, end of code is reached before complete execution of program.

Comment: try `print(data)`

Comment: Then it goes back to saying

Comment: ileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Desktop/Sro/Natrium22.csv'

Comment: Hi, @HeleneKaas you are not supposed to find File at /Desktop directly as i said do, 'C:\Users\user\Desktop....... please help yourself again