# VSCode / Pandas datetime conversion error, file not found?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, timestamp

I have a pandas data frame like below (one line sample):

```
df.sample()

    IDData    HP  Feedrate  RPM  Coolant1  Coolant2  Coolant3  Coolant4  ApproachOn  Extreme  Wear  UCut  SlopeHP  AccumulatedWork  CuttingHP       File Time Stamp Tool

60      60  1048         0    0       408         0         0         0       False        0     0     0        0                0        -22   7 1 2019 6 45 22 AM  T12
```

You can see the `File Time Stamp` column is strange. I try to run the code below:

```
df['File Time Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['File Time Stamp'], format='%m %d %Y %I %M %S %p')
```

The format is correct I believe, but I get an error in VSCode (no traceback from Python) `Unable to open 'strptime.pyx': Unable to read file (Error: File not found)`. What I don't understand is it's looking in the directory of the script I'm running, instead of the pandas folder.

For instance it's looking in `(c:\users\directory_of_my_script\pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx))` but this pandas folder does not exist obviously.

As a test I ran the same code in Jupyter Notebook and it runs fine, so it seems a VSCode issue.

Why am I getting this error? Why is it looking in the wrong directory?

Using VSCode version 1.37.1

Anaconda version 2019.03

Python version 3.7.3

Comment: don't use name `pandas` for your folder because then `import pandas` will try to load from your folder. It is not VSCode issue. It is how `import` works.

Comment: I didn't, everything after c:\users\directory_of_my_script\  is where vscode says it's trying to look, the folder pandas does not exist

Comment: Similar problem described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165649/pandas-read-csv-file-not-found-despite-correct-path-with-raw-text   VScode seems to be just much more finicky about unicode/hidden characters in a string compared to the standalone jupyter notebook server.  Only thing that worked for me was to copy full path to the file and then use a filename in form  `r"C:\Users\..."`