# How to read CSV file from a Windows path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read a CSV file from a Windows path but can't read file or folders that contain t, b as their starting letter.

For example, in the line below (in bold text):

```py
 df = pd.read_csv("G:\Datasets **\t**raining-blackfriday-Q1-Q4 **\b**lackfriday.csv",sep=",")
```

I get:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/data/training/SECTION1.csv' does not exist: b'/data/training/SECTION1.csv'
```

Comment: You need to use raw strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941695/2745495

Comment: `\t` and `\n` (and few other chars) have special meaning in strings  so you have to use \\ instead of all \ . OR use prefix `r` to create raw string `r"G:\..."`. Sometimes you can use / instead of \ in path in Windows but not all tools may respect it.