# Pandas CSV Import failing?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I know this should be the easiest thing to do... but I can't figure it out! I'm simply trying to open a file

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\erifilidraklellis\Desktop\In It Together\Excel\CSV\ii2g.csv')
```

but I keep getting the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\erifilidraklellis\\Desktop\\In It Together\\Excel\\CSV\\ii2g.csv'
```

Both the file I'm trying to open and the `jupyter` notebook are currently living in the same folder. Please help!

Comment: You can try relative path

Answer (score 2):

**You mentioned that the files are in the same folder.
Have you tried using a relative path ?**

```
pd.read_csv('ii2g.csv')
```

or

```
pd.read_csv('./ii2g.csv')
```

If you have tried these options, maybe this question posted by Impuls3H issue; [pandas.read_csv File Not Found Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165649/pandas-read-csv-filenotfounderror-file-b-xe2-x80-xaaetc-despite-correct-pat) will be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `\In It Together\` has spaces which are not being handled. Try changing the name of the file.
You could also refer to the `sep` section from [Pandas Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: I thought using `r'` dealt with that?

Comment: I thought so too and tested with a small example turns out 'r'  doesnt seem to help that case