# FileNotFoundError in JupyterLab (https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/)

Tags: jupyter-lab, filenotfounderror

Has anybody faced a FileNotFoundError in JupyterLab (https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/) when trying to read a .csv file? The file was uploaded in the same directory. I have used a CopyPath option to be sure that the path is correct. Still not working. Any suggestions on how can I fix this?

[here is a snapshot of a simple code and an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVnSp.png)

Comment: This is an issue with the demo environment which runs entirely in the browser. There are workarounds described in: https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/discussions/91

Comment: Also https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/issues/119 and https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/issues/199

Comment: Finally there is this experimental extension which bypasses the upload step altogether: https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-filesystem-access

Comment: @krassowski thanks a lot! I will dive into these resources and hope will find a workaround.

Comment: @MaxiP Also, if you want a full Python backed kernel experience like Try Jupyter used to offer, just go use the 'launch binder' badge at [the MyBinder JupyterLab demo example page](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyterlab).

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be an error with Jupyter.

Make sure that the `ReadFile.ipynb` and `theFile.csv` are in the same directory. If they are not, use a relative import.

[image]

If this still doesn't work, try the following synthax. This is independent of the path you provide.

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\aiLab\Desktop\example.csv')
```

Here `r` is a special character and means raw string. So prefix it to your string literal.

https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string:

> Python raw string is created by prefixing a string literal with ‘r’ or
> ‘R’. Python raw string treats backslash () as a literal character.
> This is useful when we want to have a string that contains backslash
> and don’t want it to be treated as an escape character.

See: [pandas.read_csv FileNotFoundError: File b'\xe2\x80\xaa<etc>' despite correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165649/pandas-read-csv-filenotfounderror-file-b-xe2-x80-xaaetc-despite-correct-pat)

Also, make sure that you don't have unwittingly copied an invisible character.

Comment: Have tried both options. Files are in the same directory. Still not working...( Suppose that it is a problem with some settings of JupyterLab (web environment). I have tried to read a file in replit web environment and everything worked fine... Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.
Make sure your working directory is the same as your notebook and .csv file. Check this by running `pwd`. You can run `ls` to get the list of files in the working directory.
If this helps you find the problem, try shutting down the running kernel completely and attaching a new one. This will change the working directory.